# Asp.net how to maintain radio button selection when using datapager

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, datapager

I am creating a quiz application in ASP.net (c#) and I currently have one question at a time displaying with the use of a datapager. However, when i move from question 1 to question 2 and then back to question 1 the radiobutton selection disappears.

EDIT - I now have the radio button retaining a selection whenever I move from next to previous, HOWEVER, If I chose radiobutton1 and then move on to question 2, It has radiobutton1 already selected, even though I am yet to answer that question. So for some reason whatever selection I make on question 1 is being duplicated to the other questions.

[Question1 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewe2I.png)
[Question2 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Bok.png)

```html
 <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:ListView ID="lvCustomers" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
                    ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging" OnPreRender="ListPager_PreRender">
    
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <div id="itemPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                        </div>
                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvCustomers" PageSize="1">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField runat="server" ButtonType="Link"
                                    ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                                    ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                                    ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link"
                                    ShowNextPageButton="true"
                                    ShowLastPageButton="false"
                                    ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QuestionID")%>'></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QuestionText")%>'></asp:Label><br />
                        <li>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="Radio1" Text='<%#Eval("Answer1") %>' GroupName="radiobtns" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="Radio2" runat="server" GroupName="radiobtns" EnableViewState="true" Text='<%#Eval("Answer2") %>' />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="Radio3" runat="server" GroupName="radiobtns" EnableViewState="true" Text='<%#Eval("Answer3") %>'  />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="Radio4" runat="server" GroupName="radiobtns" EnableViewState="true" Text='<%#Eval("Answer4") %>'   />
                        </li>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </div>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
 namespace WebApplication2.WebForms
    {
        public partial class _1QuestionQuiz : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            string userAns;
            int QuestionID;

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    BindListView();

                    if (Session["QuizID"] != null)
                    {
                        int QuizID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["QuizID"]);
                    }
                }
            }



            protected void ListPager_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Session["DTSource"] != null)
                {
                    lvCustomers.DataSource = Session["DTSource"];
                    lvCustomers.DataBind();
                }

                GetSelections();
            }


            private void BindListView()
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand();
                conn.ConnectionString = connString;

                conn.Open();

                if (lvCustomers != null)
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvCustomers.Items)
                    {
                        Label lbl = (Label)item.FindControl("Label2");

                        if (lbl != null)
                        {
                            QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text);
                            ViewState["qstion"] = QuestionID;
                        }

                        RadioButton rd1 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("Radio1");
                        RadioButton rd2 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("Radio2");
                        RadioButton rd3 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("Radio3");
                        RadioButton rd4 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("Radio4");

                        if (rd1.Checked)
                        {
                            userAns = rd1.Text;
                            ViewState["Radio1"] = rd1.Text;
                        }

                        else if (rd2.Checked)
                        {
                            userAns = rd2.Text;
                            ViewState["Radio2"] = rd2.Text;
                        }

                        else if (rd3.Checked)
                        {
                            userAns = rd3.Text;
                            ViewState["Radio3"] = rd3.Text;
                        }

                        else if (rd4.Checked)
                        {
                            userAns = rd4.Text;
                            ViewState["Radio4"] = rd4.Text;

                        }

                        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("InsertSelections", conn);
                        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("Answer", userAns);
                        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("QuestionID", QuestionID);
                        SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("QuizID", (Session["QuizID"]));
                        comm.Parameters.Add(p1);
                        comm.Parameters.Add(p2);
                        comm.Parameters.Add(p3);

                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    }
                }
            }



     private void GetSelections()
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in lvCustomers.Items)
            {
                Label lbl = (Label)item.FindControl("Label2");

                if (lbl != null)
                {
                    QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text);
                }

                RadioButton rd1 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("Radio1");
                RadioButton rd2 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("Radio2");
                RadioButton rd3 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("Radio3");
                RadioButton rd4 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("Radio4");

                        //Try radiobutton 1 as a tester
            if (rd1 != null)
            {
                if (lbl != null && ViewState["Radio1"] != null)
                {
                    rd1.Checked = true;
                }
            }
             if (rd2 != null)
            {
                if (lbl != null && ViewState["Radio2"] != null)
                {
                    rd2.Checked = true;

                }

            }
             if (rd3 != null)
            {
                if (lbl != null && ViewState["Radio3"] != null)
                {
                    rd3.Checked = true;

                }

            }
             if (rd4 != null)
            {
                if (lbl != null && ViewState["Radio4"] != null)
                {
                    rd4.Checked = true;
                    break;
                }

               }     
            }
        }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Score.aspx", false);
            }


            protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
            {
                (lvCustomers.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
                BindListView();

            }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding LoadViewState and SaveViewState to maintain the state of your radio buttons. For example, try something like the following, and pull the values back out of ViewState wherever you need them:

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);

    if (ViewState["Radio1"] != null)
        Radio1.Text = (int)ViewState["Radio1"];
    ...
}

protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    ViewState["Radio1"] = Radio1.Text;
    ...

    return base.SaveViewState();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I just tried it out and unfortunately it's still losing the radio button value :(

Comment: It's probably a life-cycle issue. TIP: Set them early and retrieve them late in the cycle - think Init and PreRender ;-)

Comment: I'm not too sure what to do with that, can you explain any further please? Cheers

Comment: Research the page life-cycle and the order in which events are raised. The general idea is to set values early and fetch them late. Sorry I don't have the time to provide a working code sample.

Comment: I've edited my code above, if there's anyway you could have a look please?

Comment: I have and I honestly don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've tried to reword it and added two images to explain what I mean!